# How do I generate LaTeX from Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: latex, isabelle

How can I use Isabelle/HOL to automatically generate LaTeX from my source theory files?

Isabelle/HOL's [`tutorial.pdf`](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/tutorial.pdf) is very beautiful. I'm going to write a paper in LaTeX with a lot of Isabelle code in it.

Comment: [Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/)—a formal mathematical logic and programming language—contains mechanisms to generate LaTeX from source files. This question is very much on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first have a look at the existing documentation and come back with more specific questions afterwards (if there remain any; but I'm sure there will ;)).

What you want to do is called *document preparation* in Isabelle. The first place to look is Chapter 4 *Presenting Theories* of
[the Isabelle System Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/system.pdf). (Actually it is also a good idea to first read the previous chapter on *Isabelle sessions and build management*.)

For some neat notation also [LaTeX Sugar for Isabelle Documents](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/sugar.pdf) might be of interest.

Some other useful things, like generating *TeX snippets* from your Isabelle theories and including them in your document (which you might collaboratively work on with others that do not have Isabelle installed), can be found on the [Community Wiki](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/community/Generate_TeX_Snippets).

Comment: Thanks, now I can use `isabelle mkroot -d` and `isabelle build -D` to do the job.