# Using antiquotes in Isabelle to refence a class defenition

Tags: latex, isabelle

Using Isabelle and the theories `LaTeXsugar OptionalSugar Archimedean_Field` where the latex documentation block contain

```
text " ... @{class floor_ceiling} ... "
```

when running `isabelle build -d . S` the process fail. The file `ROOT` contain

```
session "S" = "HOL" +
options [document = pdf, document_output = "generated"]
theories
 S
document_files
 build.sh
```

where the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421234/how-do-i-generate-latex-from-isabelle-hol) direction of was followed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make the document class a `book` int he file `root.tex`: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}`

The source of the error was `chapter "Type definition` in the thy file.